# Write-write conflicts in Cassandra atomic batches when updating multiple tables?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

The documentation on atomic batches says:

> For example, there is no batch isolation. Clients are able to read the first updated rows from the batch, while other rows are still being updated on the server.

However does a write-write conflict scenario arise when I'm updating a column in two different tables as part of a batch?

Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write%E2%80%93write_conflict

For example:

Batch 1: Table1.column = x, Table2.column = x

Batch 2: Table1.column = y, Table2.column = y

Result (write-write conflict case): Table1.column = x, Table2.column = y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quote you reference answers your question:

> For example, there is no batch isolation. Clients are able to read the first updated rows from the batch, while other rows are still being updated on the server.

However, once the batch is fully applied, normal timestamp resolution will prevail. Both cells with value X will have one timestamp. Both cells with value Y will have another timestamp. The winner will be either X or Y, but the winner will be the same, because the timestamps will be the same:

> A BATCH statement combines multiple data modification language (DML) statements (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE) into a single logical operation, and sets a client-supplied timestamp for all columns written by the statements in the batch

In this case, whether or not you see the X/Y or Y/X answers depends on the consistency level of your reads, and the time it takes for the batch to be fully applied.

Comment: Yep. That makes sense. I just wanted some confirmation on this. Thanks.